# Find overlap in sample split based on numeric columns of data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, split, cluster-computing, overlap

I have a data.frame that looks somewhat like this:

```
df <- data.frame (names  = LETTERS[1:10],
rep1 = sample(1:5, 10, replace=TRUE),
rep2 = sample(1:5, 10, replace=TRUE),
rep3 = sample(1:5, 10, replace=TRUE),
rep4= sample(1:5, 10, replace=TRUE))

print(df)
   names rep1 rep2 rep3 rep4
1      A    2    2    5    4
2      B    5    5    5    1
3      C    3    4    2    5
4      D    5    3    5    3
5      E    2    3    2    4
6      F    5    5    2    4
7      G    1    3    1    3
8      H    2    2    3    3
9      I    1    1    4    3
10     J    3    1    3    5
```

What I need to know:
Are some of the names ('samples') grouped together (by numbers) in the different reps?

However, it does not matter if the numbers (1 to 5) are different, only if specific names belong to the same group (e.g. A, E, H belong to group 2 in rep1. Are they grouped together in another rep?). I want to know if there is a 'pattern' of groupings, e.g. are some names occurring together/ in a set more often?

Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this?

Comment: How does your expected output look like?

Comment: To be honest, this is already my first struggle. I wonder what would be the best way to get an impression for the overlap. Maybe a table with 'names' as both rows and column names and a number indicating how many times the name is in the same group as another name? Or is there a plot or cluster solution?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this one helps you finding a pattern:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-names) %>% 
  group_by(name, value) %>% 
  summarise(grouping = paste(names, collapse = ", "),
            .groups = "drop") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = name,
              values_from = grouping)
```

This returns

```r
# A tibble: 5 x 5
  value rep1    rep2    rep3       rep4   
  <int> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>      <chr>  
1     1 D, E, J NA      I          A, C, E
2     2 A, B    F, H    A, C, D, F G      
3     4 F, H    D, E    H          D, H, I
4     5 C, G, I A, I, J B, J       B, F   
5     3 NA      B, C, G E, G       J
```

where `value` is the original group from the reps.

#### Data

```r
structure(list(names = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", 
"I", "J"), rep1 = c(2L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 1L), 
    rep2 = c(5L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 5L), rep3 = c(2L, 
    5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 5L), rep4 = c(1L, 5L, 1L, 
    4L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Martin Gal. I think in my reproducible example this solution would be helpful! However, my problem is that my real data frame is larger and the names are more complicated and long. So I tried it, but it is really not possible to scan this by eye...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution returning the the maximum overlap per `rep*`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(-names, names_to = "rep") %>%
  group_by(rep, value) %>%
  summarise(n = n(),
            names = paste(names, collapse = ", ")) %>%
  filter(n == max(n))
#`summarise()` has grouped output by 'name'. You can #override using the `.groups` argument.
## A tibble: 7 x 4
## Groups:   name [4]
#   rep  value     n names     
#  <chr> <int> <int> <chr>     
#1 rep1      4     4 B, C, G, I
#2 rep2      3     3 A, D, I   
#3 rep2      4     3 B, F, J   
#4 rep3      2     3 D, G, H   
#5 rep3      3     3 E, F, J   
#6 rep3      5     3 A, B, I   
#7 rep4      1     3 B, C, J
```

---

### Data

The test data creation code is repeated from the question but with the pseudo-RNG seed set, in order to make the results reproducible.

```
set.seed(2021)
df <- data.frame (names  = LETTERS[1:10],
                  rep1 = sample(1:5, 10, replace=TRUE),
                  rep2 = sample(1:5, 10, replace=TRUE),
                  rep3 = sample(1:5, 10, replace=TRUE),
                  rep4= sample(1:5, 10, replace=TRUE))
```